# MariaDB timestamp is not updating date

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just added a timestamp field to my table

i need the field to save last update without adding the instruction to each query

```
 `lastupd` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

the problem is that all field has `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and on query update `timestamp` is not updated

I'm on `5.5.60-MariaDB` - MariaDB Server and using `MyISAM` table

Comment: Is it zeros even on a newly inserted row?

Answer (score 0):

(If I recall correctly)  In that old version, such a `DEFAULT` could be applied only to the *first* `TIMESTAMP` in the table.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Please consider switching to InnoDB.

From the 5.6.6 changelog:

> In MySQL, the [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) data type differs in nonstandard ways from other data types:
>
> [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) columns not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute are assigned the NOT NULL attribute. (Columns of other data types, if not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, permit NULL values.) Setting such a column to NULL sets it to the current timestamp.
>
> The first [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) column in a table, if not declared with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause, is automatically assigned the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes.
>
> [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) columns following the first one, if not declared with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT clause, are automatically assigned DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (the “zero” timestamp). For inserted rows that specify no explicit value for such a column, the column is assigned '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and no warning occurs.
>
> Those nonstandard behaviors remain the default for [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) but now are deprecated and this warning appears at startup:
>
> [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.
>   Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see
>   documentation for more details).
>
> As indicated by the warning, to turn off the nonstandard behaviors, enable the new [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) system variable at server startup. With this variable enabled, the server handles [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) as follows instead:
>
> [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) columns not explicitly declared as NOT NULL permit NULL values. Setting such a column to NULL sets it to NULL, not the current timestamp.
>
> No [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) column is assigned the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes automatically. Those attributes must be explicitly specified.
>
> [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) columns declared as NOT NULL and without an explicit DEFAULT clause are treated as having no default value. For inserted rows that specify no explicit value for such a column, the result depends on the SQL mode. If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs. If strict SQL mode is not enabled, the column is assigned the implicit default of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and a warning occurs. This is similar to how MySQL treats other temporal types such as [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html).

Comment: I know that on older version of Maria DB it was allowed only one timestamp per table, I don't have other timestamp field only a date or datetime.

Comment: @al404IT - The snippet of the schema says `timestamp`.

Comment: before adding lastupd field I did not have any timestamp field